# Easiest way to create a custom language hilighter in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, lexer

I've been reading around, and all of the examples I've seen (including on MSDN) are incomplete or way over my head. Is there some *easy* way to create a custom language syntax hilighter for Visual Studio (as an add-in)? Basically, I just want my own filetypes to have syntax hilighting, I'm not looking to modify any of the existing color templates/languages.

Edit: I should mention that these files I want to colorize are part of an existing VB/C# project, so I can't create a new "language".

Comment: Have you downloaded the Visual Studio SDK? There's a template for this built-in. (At least, it works for adding custom syntax highlighting to *existing* supported languages. I'm not sure if it works for completely new languages, but I see no reason why not.)

Comment: I assume it doesn't work for new languages (filetypes?) because at that point you'd have to add a new language service to Visual Studio, and *that* comes with all the other bells and whistles like templates and compile options and all this other stuff, **which I don't want/need.** But yes, I do have the VSSDK.